# Turn off page caching on a single page

Tags: cache

I have page caching turned on. (The cache plugin)

This gives a problem on the contact page because it caches the _token aswell. This means only the visitor who triggers the caching for that page can use the contact form. If someone else visits the page he will get the _token from someone else.

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do that for core's cache plugin. However, there are a few options in the JED that will allow you doing exactly that:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache

This one for example should help:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache/17783